# Change size of svg used in the "content" property

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using an h3 tag and calling the :before pseudo element on that h3. In the :before pseudo element I am using the content property. Within that content property I have a link to an svg that I am using in my files.

Is it possible or impossible to control the width of an svg used in the content property?

The html looks something like this:

```
<h3>A Thank You Email and Postcard</h3>
<div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
</div>
```

The css looks something like this:

```
h3:before {

    content: url("somesvg.svg");

    /* Is it possible to change the width of the svg above without using an actual img tag before the element? */

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `width`; `height`?

Comment: Yes, I did. At first it wasn't working, but I found out that you can display it as a block / inline-block and then give it a width and height.